# freeradius prevent user to login to some devices

Tags: freeradius

How can I prevent some user to login to some network devices on freeradius server? I've created policy:

```
   deny_beli {
            if (User-Name == "belitest") {
                       reject
            }
    }
```

But I need only to ban login to network devices on subnet 172.0.0.0/23, not others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed policy:

```
   deny_beli {
            if (User-Name == "belitest") {
                    if(NAS-IP-Address =~ /172.0.0./){
                            reject
                    }
                    if(NAS-IP-Address =~ /172.0.1./){
                            reject
                    }
            }
    }
```

Now, everything is working smoothly.